# Should I concern about unknown author on my git log?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to git world and recently I need to use git on my work. When I'm doing my commit and trying to see the log, I found someone else's commit on my git log. Should I concern about this or I should leave it as it is cause it doesn't affect my work or my repository?

Comment: What is the commit? Who is the author? What changes were made? Do you work alone? Do you have multiple git workspaces with identical user/author configuration? Do you make any commits using a web-based repo (like on BitBucket)?

Comment: If you cloned an existing repo, you'll see commits from history prior to your fork. Can you post more detail?

Comment: I work alone and I just made the repository. I never use fork and any other stuff, it was straight from installing git to push the git to repository. The weird thing is that someone I don't know is made a commit two months ago when I don't have a repository.